# Using an existing field as primary key with ogr2ogr?

Tags: shapefile, postgresql, ogr, import, unique-id

I've been struggling with this for a while, tried a few different ideas inspired by these pages:

- http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html
- http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_pg.html
- http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_pg_advanced.html
- http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/ConfigOptions

But I always end up with `ogc_fid` as the primary key. **Anyone know of a way to get ogr2ogr to use an existing primary key for the fid?**

---

Alternatively, does anyone know how I can get this existing key to be an `autoincrement` sequence after the `ogr2ogr` load?

I've tried:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE my_table_my_pk_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;    

ALTER TABLE public.my_table_my_pk_seq OWNER TO postgres;    
ALTER SEQUENCE my_table_my_pk_seq OWNED BY my_table.my_pk;    
ALTER TABLE ONLY my_table ALTER COLUMN my_pk SET DEFAULT nextval('my_table_my_pk_seq'::regclass);    
ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER COLUMN my_pk SET NOT NULL;

SELECT pg_catalog.setval('my_table_ogc_fid_seq', NUMBER_OF_FEATURES_IMPORTED, true);`
```

But I get database errors when trying to insert features.

---

So, to get it to work with wfs-t, I deleted `ogc_fid` and made `my_pk` the primary key

Comment: i think it would help if you could edit your question and show us the database errors as well

Comment: Oh, not sorted actually - i.e. it works in QGIS, but my software (Open Layers using WFS-T) isn't setting the default.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add the -lco FID=[your_id_column] switch to your OGR2OGR script.

Eg.

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=myhost user=myloginname dbname=mydbname 
password=mypassword" mytabfile.shp -lco FID=id
```

Where your primary key column is called id.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get the field acting as an autoincrement - by reading this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490014/adding-serial-to-existing-column-in-postgres and then simplyfying the sql:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE my_table_my_pk_seq;
ALTER SEQUENCE my_table_my_pk_seq OWNED BY my_table.my_pk;
ALTER TABLE ONLY my_table ALTER COLUMN my_pk SET DEFAULT nextval('my_table_my_pk_seq');
ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER COLUMN my_pk SET NOT NULL;
SELECT setval('my_table_my_pk_seq', 9089);
```

I'm afraid I've lost the database errors, but on the first insert, PostgreSQL seemed to be looking for 9090 in the sequence and didn't like 9089...

I suspect the 'true' in my original `setval()` call, or maybe the 'regclass' in my original `nextval()`.